# How can I make objc functions with comma separated multiple arguements?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I would like to imitate the functionality of `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` which allows me to type in arguements this way: `[MyClass doSomethingWithObjects: @"str1",@"str2",nil]`. Assuming this is possible, how can I declare this?

Comment: Doing a bit of searching, it is possible and they are called Variable Arguement lists or va_list s. Working on solving this myself, will post here if I get it first.

Comment: Methods that take variable arguments are known as [variadic methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method with an array of inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893891/method-with-an-array-of-inputs)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found it explained here:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html

```
//interface:
 - (void)foo:(NSString *)firstString, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;

//implementation:
 - (void)foo:(NSString *)firstArg, ...
 {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstArg);
    for (NSString *arg = firstArg; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, NSString*))
    {
        [self bar:arg];
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```