# Need to understand this warning "Attributes on method implementation and its declaration must match"

Tags: ios, llvm, compiler-warnings

I have a UIView subclass used as custom alert view which declares this init method

```
@interface THAlertView : UIView   
- (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message
    cancelButtonTitle:(NSString*)cancelButtonTitle
    otherButtonTitles:(NSString*)otherButtonTitles, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
@end
```

In the implementation file I simply define that method

```
@implementation THAlertView

- (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message
   cancelButtonTitle:(NSString*)cancelButtonTitle
   otherButtonTitles:(NSString*)otherButtonTitles, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION {

// Create and return an instance of THAlertView

}
```

XCode 4.6.3 with LLVM 4.2 gives me this warning

```
THAlertView.m:74:193: warning: attributes on method implementation and its declaration must match [-Wmismatched-method-attributes]
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message cancelButtonTitle:(NSString*)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString*)otherButtonTitles, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION {
                                                                                                                                                                                               ^
THAlertView.h:29:1: note: method 'initWithTitle:message:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:' declared here
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message cancelButtonTitle:(NSString*)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString*)otherButtonTitles, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
^
1 warning generated.
```

I understand what the warning is about but this time I don't know how to fix it. To me everything seems fine but maybe I am missing something. Is it maybe because of the NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION macro?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4894023/1407017), might be useful.

Comment: That error usually means your method header is not the same as the implementation e.g. you might have -(void)doSomething:(int) param in yourClass.h file whereas -(void)doSomething:(NSString *) param { ... } in yourClass.m file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION` from the implementation file :

```
@implementation THAlertView

- (id) initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message
   cancelButtonTitle:(NSString*)cancelButtonTitle
   otherButtonTitles:(NSString*)otherButtonTitles, ... {

// Create and return an instance of THAlertView

}
```

Comment: I knew it was an easy fix. Thanks!